# How to change startIconDrawable Size in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

Seems like there is no XML attribute to change the startIconDrawable size in android. The icon is oversized as compared to the text.
Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

Here is my XML:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/textInputStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Enter Paypal ID"
                android:padding="5dp"
                app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_paypal_logo">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_form_question_hint"
                    style="@style/textInputEditext"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/normalPadding" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

If anyone wishes to reproduce styles are as follows:

```
<style name="textInputEditext" parent="FirebaseUI.TextInputEditText">
        <item name="maxLine">1</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorOnSurface</item>
    </style>

<style name="textInputStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">12dp</item>
        <item name="errorEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="endIconTint">@color/colorSurface</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/colorOnSurface</item>
        <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/Cut</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">#AA000000</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorOnSurface</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="counterTextColor">@color/colorOnSurface</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorOnSurface</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: There isn't a built-in property to change the size

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti That is really disappointing.

Answer (score 3):

There is no attribute to edit drawable size (until now).

However if you use the icon in many places in your code and you don't wanna mess with you original icon size, you can wrap it in an other drawable and change the item size there.

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:width="24dp" android:height="24dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_yourIconName" />
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Nice small trick

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you reduce the size of your TextInputLayout and shrink the icon like in:

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/your_icon"
            app:startIconScaleType="fitStart"
            app:startIconTint="@android:color/transparent"
            app:startIconTintMode="src_atop">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Important here is layout_height and startIconScaleType.

Answer (score -1):

**You can just change the size of your image.**
For example, icon with size [48x48dp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xqpJ.png) is twice as large as [24x24dp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBz7o.png), look at the screenshots. (It also works with non-vector images)